# Problem with design of Text Input Layout?

Tags: android

The label hint color doesnt works, i created the color Bluesky, but only works with the linear box but the label dont.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til1"               
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:textColorHint="@color/BlueSky"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/BlueSky"
            app:counterEnabled="true"
            app:counterMaxLength="7"
            app:errorEnabled="true"
            app:hintEnabled="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/tid1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
                android:elevation="7dp"
                android:hint="Test"
                android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
                android:maxLength="7"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

mi build gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint- 
    layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I use the version 3.4 of android studio.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

the label color on the input layout is the colorAccent of your project. If you change this color to BlueSky you'll see what you want.

```
<color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
```

But maybe there's another way to style this widget without changing the colorAccent (because this color is used by other widgets too).

Comment: Yes i want to use my own color, because i want to use different textinputlayout with different colours